# How to extract non-consecutive rows and columns of a matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

How do I extract from a matrix rows and columns that are not consecutive.
For example, in this matrix how do i extract rows 1,2 and 4 with columns 1, 2 and 4?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
               [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
               [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
               [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
               [18, 19, 20, 21, 22]])
```

So the new matrix should be:

```
b = ([[7, 8 , 10],
     [12, 13, 15],
     [19, 20, 22]])
```

Comment: What do you mean "call non consecutive"?

Comment: Your question needs more explanation.. when you say not consecutive, does it mean that you only want 1,2 and 4th row/column all the time?

Comment: non-consecutive because theres a "gap" between 2 and 4.

Comment: This is called `advanced indexing`.  The official docs are your friend: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing

Answer (score 1):

In the [doc section linked by hpaulj](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), see example starting with `From a 4x3 array the corner elements should be selected using advanced indexing.`

Specifically, the paragraph that starts `This broadcasting can also be achieved using the function ix_:`

In your case, rows are `[1, 2, 4]` and same for columns, so

```
rows = np.array([1, 2, 4], dtype=np.intp)
columns = np.array([1, 2, 4], dtype=np.intp)
b = a[np.ix_(rows, columns)]
```